# How to change what it is identified when My raspberry pi connected to android phone via bluetooth?

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi

I want to make a bluetooth device with a raspberry pi zero and it is designed for data transmission with my android phone. It was strange that rasp pi was identified as a headset like following img after raspberry pi zero connected to phone by using `bluetoothctl`. That make conflict between my bluetooth headset and raspberry pi. So could you tell me how to change that. I tried to edit the CoD (Classes of Device) code, but the changed is only the icon in phone.[image][image]

Comment: If you do `bluetoothctl show` you will see a list of UUID capabilities that the RPi comes with by default. If you don't want these capabilities then you need to start `bluetoothd` without them enabled. `service bluetooth status` will show how the service is started. And `bluetoothd -h` will show you how to remove plugins. You may also want to remove `pulseaudio` as it can interfere if you are going to be using Bluetooth Classic.